# elementary vectors addition

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $|v|=|u|=4$ and $theta=120^{\circ}$
>   , find $|u+v|$

If I draw a parallelogram and add a vertical I get a right triangle with angles $30^{\circ}$ and $60^{\circ}$ and hypotenuse is $4$

So $$\frac{\frac{|u+v|}{2}}{4}=cos(30)\iff \frac{|u+v|}{8}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\iff |u+v|=4\sqrt{3}$$

But the answer is worng

Answer (score 1):

Formula for $|u+v|^2 = |u|^2+|v|^2+2|u||v|\cos \theta=4^2+4^2+2.4.4 \cos 120=16 => |u+v|=4$

In your attempt, it will be $\cos 60$, not $\cos 30$.

Comment: Isn't it $4^2+4^2-2*4*4cos120=32-32*cos*120=48$ ?

Comment: @gbox no, The formula is as Aniket indicated. its (+) not (-).. you can check that for when vectors are parallel ( they add algebraically ), or anti-parallel (they subtract algebraically)

Comment: In Wikipedia is it -, anyhow I still get that 4 is a wrong answer

Comment: check my answer, it may be right.

Comment: @gbox what is the right answer according to the book or where you got this  question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $w = -v$. Let $\alpha$ be the angle between $u$ and $w$ (this is easy to determine).  You can use the law of cosines to find $$|u+v|^2 = |u - w|^2 = |u|^2 + |w|^2 - 2|u| |w| \cos \alpha.$$

Comment: so it is $\sqrt{48}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\alpha=120^\circ$ to be the angle between $u$ and $v$, then the angle opposite $|u+v|$ is $(360^\circ-120^\circ-120^\circ)/2=60^\circ$, so using the cosine rule gives:

$$|u+v|^2 = |u|^2+|v|^2-2|u||v|\cos 60^\circ=4^2+4^2-4^2=16,$$

so that $|u+v|=4$.

Take a look at the image below. The circle has radius 4. The angle between the two lines is $120^\circ$. You "can see" that adding the $y$-values of each intersection point of the lines with the circle, you will get $0$, and adding the $x$-values of the two intersections gives $4$. Hence $\sqrt{4^2+0^2}=4$. This would happen for any two lines whose angle between them is $120^\circ$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to me,  The angle between the vectors is the angle when their tails are joined together, but in vector addition the angle required is the angle between tail and the head of one and other. So,
$|u+v|^2 = |u|^2+|v|^2+2|u||v|cos(180-\theta)$

Hence the answer computes to,
$u+v=\sqrt{16+16+16} = 4\sqrt{3}$

Which should be the answer.